# can we share site authentication cookie?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i have two web site domain1.com and domain2.com user come in domain1.com and i authenticate

it and create authenticate cookie ,is it possible to share this cookie by domain2.com,for

example when user Soto domain2.com is authenticated because it authenticated in domain1.com?

```
is it possible?
I'm looking for a simple way and these domains are not 
a sub domains they are two separate site
```

notice i don't want use sql server url parameter or other ways

thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely.  Hopefully both sites share the same username database or it is replicated so that you can secure and access content by using the `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name`.

Anyways, basically you need to update your web.config `<authentication>` section to be exactly the same between the two sites.  This means your machine key, decryption key, algorithm....everything.

[Here is the MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) with the full directions on how to proceed to share authentication across several applications

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using `<authentication>` and `<machineKey>` in your web config.

Machine Key
Contains a decrytion key and validation key.  This must be the same in both web configs.

```
<machineKey
 decryptionKey="A225194E99BCCB0F6B92BC9D82F12C2907BD07CF069BC8B4"
 validationKey="6FA5B7DB89076816248243B8FD7336CCA360DAF8" />
```

Auhentication
This must be in both web configs but the values are specific to the application.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" 
         path="/" 
         loginUrl="~Membership/login"
         protection="ALL"
         timeout="1000" />
</authentication>
```